# Trying to submit a web form Python 3 (have old python 2 code...need help converting)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, urllib2, urllib

Here is the python 2 code taken from a tutorial
http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/06/08/python-101-how-to-submit-a-web-form/

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import webbrowser

data = urllib.urlencode({'q': 'Python'})
url = 'http://duckduckgo.com/html/'
full_url = url + '?' + data
response = urllib2.urlopen(full_url)
with open("results.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(response.read())

webbrowser.open("results.html")
```

I'm trying to convert  this code into python 3, but I am having troubles...
Any advice or tips for a new pythoner would be very appreciated.

```
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen
import webbrowser

data = urllib.urlencode({'hello there': 'Python'})
url = "http://duckduckgo.com/html/"
full_url = url + '?' + data
response = urllib.request(full_url)
with open("results.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(response.read())

webbrowser.open("results.html")
```

I'm getting an error saying
unspported operand types(s) for +: 'HTTPResponse' and 'str'

Comment: Try using `2to3`.

Comment: @Ouroborus Oh, I fixed that typo. Though, the code still doesn't run.